# Mocking types that are template parameters of return types for methods that I also need to mock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, future

I'm writing some code that uses a 3rd party library. The library in question provides an API in terms of concrete classes, not interfaces. This makes it difficult to write tests that would target MY code and would not depend on the details of the library implementation.

As I understand, the standard practice is to have an interface that provides the same functionality as the library. Then I can wrap the library (or parts of it) in a class that implements the new interface. And I can have other (mock) subclasses of the interface that can be used for testing of my code.

The part of the library that I need to have mocks for looks approximately like this.

```cpp
class Connection {
public:
    ...
    future<shared_ptr<Widget>> CreateWidget();
    ...
};
```

I will need mocks for both of the types: `Connection` and `Widget`. Let's say I have an interface called `IWrapperConnection`. It could have a method with the following signature: `future<shared_ptr<IWrapperWidget>> CreateWidget()`. But this approach will not work because the library returns `future<shared_ptr<Widget>>` and I have no control over that.

Seems like I need something like a way to convert a `future<X>` into a `future<Y>` using a function `Y func(const X& x)` or something like that.

Please advise how to proceed in this situation.

Comment: You can create a wrapper (a gateway of kinds) - Your code only ever calls methods on wrapper, wrapper translates that to library calls. This way you have full control and can separate library from your code, you control the interface and the types returned. Check out [Adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) or Facade pattern.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, thanks. I know that wrapping is the standard approach. But my question is HOW to do this if the class to be wrapped has a method returning `future<X>`, where `X` is another type that I need to wrap.

Comment: Wrap `Widget` as well - `WidgetWrapper` can store `Widget` object and pass the calls to it, and your `LibraryWrapper::CreateWidget` will return `std::future<std::shared_ptr<IWidgetWrapper>>`

Comment: And how will my LibraryWrapper do that if the actual library returns `future<shared_ptr<Widget>>`? Can you please sketch how I would implement LibraryWrapper::CreateWidget()?